# Python Beautiful Soup crawl text data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie to python and I am trying to crawl some text comments from a website using beautifulSoup in Python. Part of the html structure is as follows,

```
<div style="1st level">
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 1</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 2</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 3</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 4</div>
    Here is text 5 and this is the part I want to get.
<div>
```

So the text 1,2,3,4 is at the 2nd level and I don't need these text. I only want to get text 5 which is at the 1st level of the structure. Part of my code is like:

```
reviews=soup.find('div',style="1st level")
reviews=reviews.text
print reviews
```

But then I got all from text 1 to text 5. Is there a simple way that I can locate to the 1st level and only get text 5?

Comment: We're almost definitely going to need the html source code from the website in question to help you out with this.

Comment: I went to fix your question formatting and saw that some html source was there (though, not enough).  Please edit your post, insert the actual html source, and make sure the formatting is correct.

Comment: Aer you sure those `style=`'s shouldn't be `class=`'s ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure these methods are the best but give them a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import deque


input = """<div style="1st level">
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 1</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 2</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 3</div>
    <div style="2nd level">Here is text 4</div>
    Here is text 5 and this is the part I want to get.
<div>"""

web_soup = soup(input)
reviews = web_soup.find('div', style="1st level")

print reviews.contents[-2]
print deque(reviews.strings, maxlen=1).pop()
```

both prints:

```
Here is text 5 and this is the part I want to get.
```

FYI, I've used `deque` to get the last element from the `strings` generator.

And, FYI, lxml + xpath would do the job easier by making use of `text()`.

Hope that helps.